# 3-stack implementation with a single array

Tags: c++, stack

I'm teaching myself data structures and would really appreciate some feedback on my stack implementation.

A couple of things I'm not sure if I should be doing:

- creation of the array and pointer using `new`
- style

```
// Implement 3 stacks with one array 
#include <iostream>


class SingleArrayStacks{
    private:
        int stack_size;
        int *array;
        int *pointers;
        int get_top_position(int stack_num){
            return (stack_num * stack_num)  + pointers[stack_num]; 
        }

    public:
        SingleArrayStacks (int array_size = 100, int num_stacks = 3) {
            array = new int[array_size];    
            pointers = new int[num_stacks]; 
            stack_size =  array_size / num_stacks;
            std::fill_n(pointers, num_stacks, -1);
        }

        ~SingleArrayStacks (){
            delete[] array;
            delete[] pointers;
        }

        void print_stack (int stack_num) const {
            std::cout << "Current stack state: ";
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++) {
                std::cout << array[i];
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

        bool is_empty(int stack_num) const {
            return pointer[stack_num] == -1; 
        }

        void push (int stack_num, int val) {
            if (pointers[stack_num] > stack_size) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Stack is full");
            } else {
                array[get_top_position(stack_num) + 1] = val;
                pointers[stack_num]++;
            }
        }

        int pop(int stack_num){
            if (is_empty(stack_num) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Stack is empty");
            } else {
                int val = array[get_top_position(stack_num)];
                array[get_top_position(stack_num)] = NULL;
                pointers[stack_num]--;
                return val;
            }
        }

        int top(int stack_num){
            if (is_empty(stack_num) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Stack is empty");
            } else {
                return array[get_top_position(stack_num)];
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: you can't use sizeof(array) to determine the size of the array. You need to store the array's size that is defined in the constructor as a class variable

Comment: Your code is not compiling properly, which would be off-topic for this site. Next time make sure your code works as you intended, before posting it for a code review. Check out the [help-center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Compiler errors:

You code did not compile under Clang! It would not compiler anywhere for that matter, as it has a few syntax errors:

- In method `is_empty()`, `pointer` is not declared. It should be `pointers` (plural).
- In both `pop()` and `top()` methods, this line is broken:

  > ```
  > if (is_empty(stack_num) {
  > //                    ^-------- Missing a `)` here!
  > ```

#### Compiler warnings:

Always compile with warnings *turned on* and set them to the highest level practical.
If you have the habit of ignoring warnings, try compiling with "warnings as errors" (`-Werror` for Clang and GCC) to force yourself into fixing them.

That said, your code only produced one warning, after the errors above where fixed:

> ```
> array[get_top_position(stack_num)] = NULL;
> //                                   ^^^^--------- implicit conversion of NULL constant to 'int'
> ```

`NULL` is not the same as `int`. In fact, an implementation is free to define `NULL` to whatever, so don't assume it will be convertible to an integer on all compilers/platforms.

#### Code review:

Now if I get the idea behind your code, you intend to have a single array with several stack
sharing this array. Your implementation doesn't seem to be doing that correctly. I could not test it thoroughly, but the helper array `pointers`, which doesn't store pointers by the way, seems questionable. The method `get_top_position()` also seems a bit contrived to me. `print_stack()` is broken, so I couldn't print the stacks to validate the state of the structure.

I would suggest that you attempt to simplify this by storing actual pointers (or indexes) to the sub-array inside the main array. Then you won't need any additional offset calculation once pushing/poping. You also have the advantage that all stacks share the same size.

```
               main array of ints:
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+----
    |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ...
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+----
    |           |           |           |
    V           V           V           V
    +-----------+-----------+-----------+----
    |  stack 0  |  stack 1  |  stack 2  | ...
    +-----------+-----------+-----------+----
    |           |           |           |
    V           V           V           V
pointer[0]  pointer[1]  pointer[2]  pointer[N] ...
```

#### Overall code improvements:

- `sizeof` misuse: This is not doing what you expect:

  > ```
  > for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++) {
  > ```

  `sizeof` is a *compile-time* operator, so it cannot infer the size of dynamically allocated arrays, only arrays in which the size is known at compile-time (e.g.: `char buf[128]`) can have the size inferred with `sizeof`. You must keep a member variable with the size of the stacks and another with the main array's.
- `top()` only inspect data, so it should also be a `const` method.
- Simplify `if-else` logic where it is not needed. Example:

  > ```
  > if (is_empty(stack_num)) {
  >     throw std::runtime_error("Stack is empty");
  > } else {
  >     return array[get_top_position(stack_num)];
  > }
  > ```

  No need to keep the `if-else` when both paths will exit the function.

  ```
  if (is_empty(stack_num)) {
      throw std::runtime_error("Stack is empty");
  }
  return array[get_top_position(stack_num)];
  ```
- Instead of hardcoding `cout` in `print_stack()`, you could take the output parameter as an `std::ostream &`. However, such function is asking to become an [output stream operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/).
- Manual memory management (with `new/delete`) is a dated practiced in C++. Even for custom containers, the use of **smart pointers** is strongly advised. I would replace the raw pointers by at least a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or even better a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).